# Mobile data disabled notification

Tags: notifications

After upgrading to marshmallo i get that notification (mobile data is disabled) ,when i swipe it , it appears again,  for sure I know that mobile data is disabled ,i use mobile data rarely. It keeps bothering me.
How to stop it